# LRU cache algorithm

Tags: algorithm, caching, lru

I need an LRU algorithm for a 4-way associative cache having additional 5 bits per set to indicate which line should be evicted.

```
       -------------------------------------
Set x: | line_0 | line_1 | line_2 | line_3 |
       -------------------------------------
```

```
      -----------------------------------------
      | bit_4 | bit_3 | bit_2 | bit_1 | bit_0 |
      -----------------------------------------
```

At first, I tried to divide my problem into smaller ones.
Having only two lines, I would fire bit corresponding to currently used line at the same time setting other one to 0.

The victim would be the line with bit set to 0 (provided that set is full).

I thought I could use this in a 4-way cache having bits `bit_4`, `bit_3`, `bit_1`, `bit_0` corresponding to `line_0`, `line_1`, `line_2`, `line_3` and a middle bit to indicate which side was used most recently. Quickly I realised that it is not precise enough. I.e. after a sequence  `line_0`, `line_2`, `line_3`, `line_1` the bits would be: 10101, that would indicate that the left side was referenced most recently (which is true) but this does not necessarily mean that side wasn't referenced least recently.

I would be very grateful for any hints.

Comment: Maybe this help: https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/smitha/ParaCache/ParaCache/sa4.html

Comment: I do appreciate your help, this application provides great caching simulation but it's not necessarily solving my problem. I do understand how it works but I seem to get stuck on how to use 5 bits to indicate least recently used line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to consistently find the least recently used item, you need to keep track of the order in which the 4 cache lines have been most recently used.

There are 4! possible orderings.  4! is 24 possibilities, and there are 32 possible configurations of your extra 5 bits, so you have enough bits (yay!).  You don't have a lot of extra bits, though, so you can't really expect the encoding of the order to be super easy to work with.

Off the top of my head, I think I would do it like this:

- 2 bits for the least recently used item: 0-3.  This is the one to evict if you need to.
- 2 bits for the 2nd least recently used item: 0-3
- 1 bit for the 3rd least recently used item.  There are only two possibilities, because the other two are already used.  0 means the remaining cache line with the smaller number.
- 0 bits for the most recently use (4th least recently used).  There's only one left, so you don't need to store anything to know which one it is.

Comment: This is really helpful! Trying to reimplement my algorithm I thought "Ok but what happens if one of those lines used is 0? How do I know whether it's actually been accessed or not?" And I realised I can use a number of dirty bits that are set to 1 (correct me if I'm wrong) to indicate how many of those lines were actually modified!

Comment: Why not just store the permutation index? No need to fiddle with bits.

Comment: True, my solution would be very inefficient. So the other idea would be to create something like table where I would associate a number from 1-24 with particular permutation (not actually implementing it). In case when not all lines in my set are valid I guess it would be ok to chose a random permutation that stores the right order of recently accessed lines (i.e. when accessing line_0 then line_3 any xx30 permutation would fit since first two lines are equally least recently accessed. So what I would do is describe steps for each possible transition. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: @Dialecticus It doesn't make much difference, but it might be nice to minimize the number of lookup tables required in the implementation.

Comment: @wkkuna yes, the ordering of invalid lines just doesn't matter, as long as you use them first.  Implementation will require 2 transition functions.  HIT: State, Line -> State, that you use to get the next state after a cache hit, and one MISS: State -> State, Line, that you use to get the new state and line to evict after a cache miss.